# Why does Object not going at expected speed - android studio animation

Tags: android, animation, game-development

```
package com.example.ballonstd6;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Bullet extends View {
    public int power;

    public int delay;
    public int x,y; // starting points;

    public Balloon currentTarget;

    public int[] targetPos;

    public Bitmap bulletImage;

    public Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.dartmonkeylevel1bullet);

    public MonkeyAbstract currentMonkey;
    Rect rect;

    public double currentAngle;

    private double speed = 70;

    private boolean isShot = false;

    private long prevFrameTime;





    public Bullet(Context context, int power, int delay, Balloon currentTarget, MonkeyAbstract currentMonkey) {
        super(context);
        this.power = power;
        this.delay = delay;
        this.currentTarget = currentTarget;
        rect = new Rect();
        this.currentMonkey = currentMonkey;
        currentAngle = currentMonkey.angle;
        targetPos = new int[2];

        prevFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(currentTarget.isPopped == false){
            if(isShot == false){
                CalculateOriginBulletPoint();
                bulletImage = AdjustLookingDirection(originalBitmap);
                Log.i("tag", "targetX: " + targetPos[0] + " TargetY: " + targetPos[1]);
            }
            checkForPopping();
            arrowShoot();
            resetPosition();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);

            int drawX = x - bulletImage.getWidth()/2;
            int drawY = y - bulletImage.getHeight()/2;

            rect.set(drawX,drawY, drawX + bulletImage.getWidth(), drawY + bulletImage.getHeight());


            if(bulletImage != null){
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = bulletImage;

                int rotatedWidth = rotatedBitmap.getWidth();
                int rotatedHeight = rotatedBitmap.getHeight();

                int rotatedDrawX = x - rotatedWidth / 2;
                int rotatedDrawY = y - rotatedHeight / 2;

                rect.set(rotatedDrawX, rotatedDrawY,rotatedDrawX + rotatedWidth, rotatedDrawY + rotatedHeight);

                canvas.drawBitmap(rotatedBitmap,null,rect,paint);

            }
        }
    }

    public void setRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        this.bulletImage = bitmap;
    }

    private double CalculateAngle(){
        double adj = targetPos[0] - this.x;
        double opp = targetPos[1] - this.y;
        currentAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(opp,adj));
        return currentAngle;
    }

    private Bitmap AdjustLookingDirection(Bitmap bitmap){
        float angle = (float)CalculateAngle();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(angle,x + bitmap.getWidth()/2, y + bitmap.getHeight()/2);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,false);
    }


    public void CalculateOriginBulletPoint(){

        double radianAngle = Math.toRadians(currentMonkey.angle);
        int monkeyOriginX = currentMonkey.x;
        int monkeyOriginY = currentMonkey.y;

        int weaponLength = currentMonkey.monkeyImage.getWidth()/2;

        int deltaX =(int) (weaponLength * Math.cos(radianAngle));
        int deltaY =(int) (weaponLength * Math.sin(radianAngle));

        int arrowX = monkeyOriginX + deltaX;
        int arrowY = monkeyOriginY + deltaY;

        this.x = arrowX;
        this.y = arrowY;
    }

    public void resetPosition(){
        if(x > GameController.screenWidth || x<0 || y>GameController.screenHeight || y<0){
            isShot = false;
        }
    }


    public void arrowShoot(){
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTimeMillis = currentTime - prevFrameTime;

        // Update previous frame time
        prevFrameTime = currentTime;

        targetPos = currentTarget.calculateFuturePositionOnPath();
        adjustSpeed(elapsedTimeMillis);

        double radianAngle = Math.toRadians(currentAngle);
        int deltaX = (int) (speed * Math.cos(radianAngle));
        int deltaY = (int) (speed * Math.sin(radianAngle));
        x += deltaX;
        y += deltaY;
        isShot = true;

        Log.d("ArrowShoot", "DeltaX: " + deltaX + ", DeltaY: " + deltaY);




    }

    private void checkForPopping(){
        if(currentTarget.isPointInsideBoundingCircle(x,y)){
            isShot = false;
            CalculateOriginBulletPoint();
            currentTarget.isPopped=true;
        }
    }

    public void adjustSpeed(long elapsedTimeMillis){
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(targetPos[0] - 2120, 2) + Math.pow(targetPos[1] - 783, 2));
        double bulletSpeed = (double) (distance / elapsedTimeMillis);
    

      //  Log.i("tag", "bullet speed:" + bulletSpeed);
        Log.d("AdjustSpeed", "Distance: " + distance + ", Bullet Speed: " + bulletSpeed
        + ", ElapsedTime:" + elapsedTimeMillis);

        speed = bulletSpeed;

    }








}

public int[] calculateFuturePositionOnPath(){

        PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(currentPath,false);

        float pathLength = pathMeasure.getLength();

        long timePassed = (long) (duration * currentVal);
        //Log.i("TimePassed", "TimePassed" + timePassed);
        long futureTime = (long) (timePassed + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1) );

        //Log.i("futureTime", "Future"+ futureTime);

        //Log.i("duration", "Duration: "+ duration);
        float valFutureDistance =  (float) futureTime / duration;

        //Log.i("futureVal",  "Val" + valFutureDistance);

        float futureDistance = valFutureDistance * pathLength;

        float[] futurePosition = new float[2];
        pathMeasure.getPosTan(futureDistance,futurePosition,null);

        int futureX = (int) futurePosition[0];
        int futureY = (int) futurePosition[1];

        //Log.i("PointFromBalloon", "X: " + futureX + " Y: " + futureY);



        int[] points = {futureX,futureY};



        return points;
    }
```

So the problem is this: the arrow I created - Bullet class instance is suppose to reach a certain point at my screen within a selected time limit, as you can see in adjustSpeed function I tried using Elapsed time that I calculated(ChatGpt recommended to do it) and it did not work, In addition I tried just writing 1 ( I want the arrow to reach the point after 1 second so I divide the distance between the origin point of arrow to the target point in the desired reach time), this value is then inserted into the speed and arrowShoot then moves the arrow in selected angle at selected speed. Please help me guys, been sitting for hours and do not understand how to determine the desired speed, again - the speed need to be X so after 1 second the arrow will get to target Point. :)